# Recaptcha in Form

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have almost the same form as given the following URL:

URL: [PHP form + Google reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681060/php-form-google-recaptcha)

But after including the PHP code to my website-(www.obzservices.com) given in the answer, my website is just showing me the pre-loader icon i.e. my website is not loading up. I have edit my PHP Code previously by adding my Site Key, adding $name, $title, $location etc but it didn't help. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: QuoteForm';
    $to = 'obaid@obzservices.com';
    $subject = 'Quote Request';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Title: $title\n Location: $location\n Industry: $industry\n Quantity: $quantity\n Message:\n $message";


    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($email != '') {
            if(mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';

            } else {
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
            }
        }

    }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following simpleScript

```
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
 <script>

   function get_action(form) 
 {
 var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if(v.length == 0)
   {
document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="You can't leave Captcha Code empty";
return false;
 }
  else
  {
document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="Captcha completed";
return true; 
}
    }

</script>
```

and add this HTML before your submit button:

```
 <span id="captcha" style="color:red" /></span> 
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="rcaptcha"  data-sitekey="site key"></div>
```

Add this to your form

```
onSubmit="return get_action()" such  As below
  <form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return get_action()">
```

Comment: I applied this but when I tried I was able to submit the form even without solving the captcha.

Comment: I have updated my answer Also, Where did you add the javascript ?

Comment: Add this above the html

Comment: I have tried adding the javascript before <html> and before </head> both. But failed in both conditions. I have edited my PHP code above. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Comment: I have checked your code, there is nothing to do with captcha.

Comment: Perfect. It's working now. Thank you very much :)
Now, if i don't want this "Captcha Error" or "Captcha Completed" written over there?

Comment: you can remove  <span id="captcha" style="color:red" /></span>  if you don't want this "Captcha Error"