# Google reCaptcha 2.0 not working, Is it for curl?

Tags: php, recaptcha

after several trying (Explicitly render), I finally show the `reCaptcha` in my website.

Inside `<head></head>` tag..

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

and inside my form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Enter Your Name" type="text" required/>
    <input placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="email" required/>
    <input placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" required/>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My_reCaptcha_Site_Key"></div>
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

and my `php` code is

```
<?php
$msg='';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    if(!empty($recaptcha)){
        include 'getCurlData.php';
        $google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $secret='My_reCaptcha_Secret_Key';
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
        $res=getCurlData($url);
        $res= json_decode($res, true);
        //reCaptcha success check 
        if($res['success']){
            $msg="Your reCAPTCHA succeeded.";
        } else {
            $msg="Please re-enter your reCAPTCHA 1.";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="Please re-enter your reCAPTCHA 2.";
    }
}
?>
```

and my `getCurlData.php` code is like

```
<?php
function getCurlData($url){
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $curlData;
}
?>
```

I have given you the entire details which I've tried. But the problem is, `reCaptcha` not succeeded. Means, it is showing the tick mark but the `$msg` showing "Please re-enter your reCAPTCHA 1." I am unable to find the error.

For your information, I am testing it in `localhost`, and if succeeded, I will upload it in my `GoDaddy` hosting site.

I have found [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274157/new-google-recaptcha-with-checkbox-server-side-php?rq=1), but not worked.

**Update:**

As per Stretch, I tried

```
$res=file_get_contents($url);
```

instead of

```
getCurlData($url);
```

And the problem solved. However I am putting my question open.

**So is there no need of `curl` ?** Why should we use `curl` in `reCaptcha` ?

Comment: Instead of `getCurlData()` try `file_get_contents()` and see what happens.

Comment: file_get_contents() will only work if allow_url_fopen is set to 1 in your php ini file. Often you cannot change the php ini file on your live server because you are on shared hosting. In that case you can rely on Curl.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because you're trying to access HTTPS. The solution you shouldn't use is this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The solution you should use is this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/316732/364841 has a link to the latest cacert.pem.