# Testing recaptcha on localhost

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've been trying to test recaptcha on `localhost` (`xampp` with php 5.3); the code below (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30749288/889604)) works on my remote host and returns `'success':'true'`, but on localhost `{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }` is returned. However, if I change the POST request to a GET request (essentially toggle the comment of the 2 `$result =` lines), then I get a successful call.

Why does this happen?! Although I'm happy that it works on my actual site, I'd like to understand *why* GET works but POST doesn't on localhost

```
<html><head></head><body><script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer>
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $data = array('secret'   => 'my_secret_key',
              'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

  $options = array(
      'http' => array(
      'method'  => "POST",
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" . PHP_EOL,
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
  );

  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  //$result = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=my_secretkey&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  echo $result;
}
?>

<form method="post" action='recaptchatest.php'>
<input id="test" name="test" />
<div style="left:100px;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="buttons" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

For completeness, the output of `http_build_query($data)` is a correctly formed query string (`secret=<my key>&response=<response>`) and the output of `stream_context_create($options)` is `Resource id #3`

Comment: are the stream functions installed on localhost?

Comment: @Dagon yes (when I echo `$context`, I get `resourceid #9`)