# Ajax call not working properly when used with Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I am using PHP and AJAX together in my website to fetch data from a JSON URL and to display it on the webpage. When I use it without implementing recaptcha, it works fine but when I integrate Google's Recaptcha, the results get displayed only when the captcha puzzle is solved twice everytime. I am not sure where the bug actually lies and I even tried to implement a custom captcha and in that case also it is the same. Here is the code with recaptcha,

Captcha and Ajax code snippet :

```
<?php
if ($resp != null && $resp->success):  ?>

echo"hi";

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){

$.post("retrieve_train_between_stations.php", $("#get_train_running").serialize(),  function(response) {  
 $("#success").html(response);


});
return false;


});

});
</script>


<?php
else:
echo "Failed";

?>
```

Full code : 
http://pastebin.com/UynEiYng

Comment: Given your script, that is the expected behavior.

Comment: Where am I going wrong ?  Is there any solution for the problem ?  @frz3993

Comment: The first load of the script `$_POST` doesn't exist, so `$resp` will be false and your script part doesn't exist. On the first submit `$_POST` will be populated and `$resp` will become true, script part comes into existence. Only on the second submit will the script be effective.

Comment: My suggestion, make `retrieve_train_between_stations.php` check for the recaptcha, make the script always available (drop the if/else), prevent default behavior when submit is clicked. And also check if `isset($_POST)`.

Comment: @frz3993 : Oh Thank you so much for your suggestion I will try that and let you know ! Thank you once again !

Comment: @frz3993 : I tried what you said , but couldn't get to work either can you please help me out with a sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part should be moved to `retrieve_train_between_stations.php`.

```
require_once "recaptchalib.php";
// your secret key
$secret = "My secret key"; 
// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

$resp = false;

if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
    $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

if ($resp) {
    //display the record
} else {
    echo 'Recaptcha can not be verified.';
}
```

The if/else should be removed and prevent the default event for the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("retrieve_train_between_stations.php", $("#get_train_running").serialize(),  function(response) {  
 $("#success").html(response);


        });
        return false;

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I will try this one and will inform you whether it works or not.

Comment: I did like this : http://pastebin.com/vBE5UF3G
but now it is not giving me back results.

Comment: I can see that you are trying to use `$resp` in a function context. You will need to pass it as argument to the function or use `$_GLOBAL` so it can be used inside a function context. Within the function context `$resp` will be undeclared.

Comment: Yes you are correct ! I didn't realize that ! Now I changed it and it works fine :) Thanks a lot and another solution also I found on stackoverflow, here is the alternative : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274157/new-google-recaptcha-with-checkbox-server-side-php

Hope it helps :)