# Adding ReCaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, recaptcha

I am having a very difficult time attempting to implement GOOGLE reCAPTCHA on a website I designed years back. It uses a PHP template and the form use the CGI bin to process the information. Is there an easy way to implement this? Seems silly that GOOGLE does not have a simple call to integrate this as I would assume they are wanting to have a more safer more secure web.

Here is a test page I am using to figure this out.
https://www.queensmaidcleaningservice.com/test.html

My experience..

I am a web designer. I am experienced in html and CSS coding and can locate and modify some JavaScript. I am not a full stack developer.

I have generated the key and added the following to the to the  section...

I then added the badge above the submit button....

```js
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/contact.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Of course, all this does is display the badge.

Server Side Verification is where I get stuck. I have tried following GOOGLE's instructions on this and it does not explain "how to" very well.

Again, here is a test page I am using to figure this out.
https://www.queensmaidcleaningservice.com/test.html

Does anyone have a fairly straight forward and simple "method" to implement this on a standard, basic contact form or possibly and easier alternative? Very frustrating as it baffles me they make it so difficult to validate on the server.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to make an HTTP request to Google in order to validate the response submitted client-side.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322745/6472849

Comment: Hello,  Thank you for your reply. I guess I'm not sure on this still. Was hoping there would be a better step by step process for this. Where would I add this code (the curl)? Do I have to create a separate php file and add the code there? How do I validate?