# Send URL-encoded parameters in Node.js using request module

Tags: node.js, request, npm, pastebin

I am trying to [create a new paste using the PasteBin API](http://pastebin.com/api#2) with `request` module like so:

```
var request = require("request");
request({
    url : "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php",
    method : "POST",
    qs : {
        "api_dev_key" : MY_DEV_KEY,
        "api_option" : "paste",
        "api_paste_code" : "random text"
    }
},function(err,res,body){
    ...
});
```

My understanding is that since the method is `POST` and querystring parameters are provided, the values in `qs` object will be stored as `key=value` pairs in the body. (Ref: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request))

However, I get back a `Bad API request, invalid api_option` from PasteBin. So I `curl`ed the request from my terminal like so:

```
curl -X POST "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php" -d "api_dev_key=[MY_DEV_KEY]&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=some+random+text"
```

and this worked.

So this leads to two questions:

1. How exactly are the parameters sent when a `POST` request is made and `qs` is provided?
2. How do I send URL-encoded body using just the `request` module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rename the `qs` key to `form` in the object. The `qs` key is for specifying the query string on the end of the URL (e.g. For GET requests). The `form` key is for specifying the form URL encoded request body (e.g. For a POST request).

Comment: I came to my conclusion (that `POST` + `qs` = url-encoded body) because some APIs (that state they want a url-encoded body) work fine if I use `qs` instead of `form` while making a `POST` request. Any insight into this? (:

Comment: @LittleChild my best guess is that those APIs are doing something like `body = req.body || req.query` or something like that. Meaning that it will look for the POST data in either the body of the request or in the query string.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, `POST` is used for sending sensitive data that shouldn't be sent as a part of the URL. So the APIs that allow data to be sent as querystring (whilst mentioning url-encoded body in the documentation) are exposing the data for everyone to see?

Comment: @LittleChild so long as you're sending the request to an HTTPS endpoint you should be fine. The connection to the SSL endpoint is established before the `path` header is sent (which would contain the query string). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/323286/1397319

Comment: Thanks a ton, mate! The link to the SO question answered another question I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

the same issue for me and my resolution which is perfectly working for me is.

```
request.post({
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
},
url : "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php",
body : "api_dev_key=MY_DEV_KEY&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=andom text"},function(err,res,body){  ...});
```