# Web API 2 GET by query parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm going to switch from my WCF Rest/Json Service to WebApi2 and I'm looking for a way to map this method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Users?mail={mail}&pw={pw}")]
UserData getUserByEmailAndPw(String mail);
```

I want to query a user by email and password so I can't use the default GET which is intended to use an ID. As far as I know you should do this via attributes in Rest...

Do I just have to register a route for this or is there a better way (maybe by convention) ?

Comment: I know this is old, but for new viewers of this question: passing Password (or any sensitive data) in the query string is generally considered bad practice.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/323286/2391294

Comment: Agree! But this was just a sample and the questions was "How to create GET with query parameter"...

Comment: Cool, completely understand. Just wanted to point it out for newbies doing the "Copy & Paste from StackOverflow" thing. 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You always have to register a route in *WebApi* for your controller actions, this can be done with [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) or with [conventions based routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Parameters passed in the query string for GET request don't really have to be specified explicitly in either of the routing configuration methods.

The parameters you specify on your controller action get mapped to parameters sent in the query string of a GET request.

If you are using the default WebApi conventions based setup where the routes are configured something like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
// some other config setup for web api
...
...
// route config
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then a controller like this will work for you:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController {
   // this maps to a get requests to:
   // domain/api/users
   // and domain/api/users?id=someid
   // and domain/api/users?mail=somemail
   // and domain/api/users?pw=somepw
   // and domain/api/users?mail=somemail&pw=somepw
   // and domain/api/users with any query string really
   [HttpGet]
   public IHttpActionResult Get(string mail, string pw) {
      // should probably check mail and pw for empty strings and nulls
      var users = SomeStaticExampleService.FindByMailAndPw(mail, pw);
      return this.Json(users);
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can use attribute routing and then call your controllers and action methods whatever you want. Configure your routes like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
// some other config setup for web api
...
...
// route config
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then you can create a controller like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController {
   // this maps to a get requests to:
   // domain/users
   // and domain/users?id=someid
   // and domain/users?mail=somemail
   // and domain/users?pw=somepw
   // and domain/users with any query string really
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("users")]
   public IHttpActionResult Bar(string mail, string pw) {
      // should probably check mail and pw for empty strings and nulls
      var users = SomeStaticExampleService.FindByMailAndPw(mail, pw);
      return this.Json(users);
   }
}
```

Bear in mind though that with *Attribute Routing* you have to be careful not to create clashing routes otherwise *WebApi* won't know which controller and action to route a request to when a route is mapped to multiple action methods.

I've used `this.Json` in these examples to return a http response with json content to match your *wcf* `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`. But you can of course just return a *CLR* type:

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("users")]
   public IEnumerable<MyUser> Bar(string mail, string pw) {
      // should probably check mail and pw for empty strings and nulls
      var users = SomeStaticExampleService.FindByMailAndPw(mail, pw);
      return users;
   }
```

and let *WebApi's* [content negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) handle the response message content type.

Comment: What if you want to combine URL params with query params, e.g., /users/4333?open=yes&closed=maybe ?

Comment: @user1944491 You can use the `[FromUri]` attribute on the parameter like this `public IEnumerable<MyUser> Bar([FromUri]string id, string open, string closed)` with your route defined like this `[Route("users/{id}")]`