# Can I use the passport-google callback to authenticate android/ios users?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, google-signin

I have a node.js server which authenticates using google-passport-oauth2.  My server-side code looks like that from [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth2#authenticate-requests):

```
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 
        [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read' ] }
));

app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        successRedirect: '/auth/google/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure'
}));
```

I figure that `/auth/google` redirects to google's login, and when permissions are recieved, the google profile and token are sent to the callback `/auth/google/callback`.

Now I am making an android app which wants to authenticate with this API.  I'm using the [directions for integrating Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) to do the authentication on google's end.  Now my android app has the profile and token and wants to [verify it with my server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).

I've tried doing this with [`passport-google-token`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-token) and [`passport-google-id-token`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-id-token) (not sure the difference...), but it didn't work for whatever reason.  Now I'm looking at other possibilities, like a Google Client API library for node.js, but it seems bulky.  Then there's the tokeninfo endpoint, which involves an extra request and more latency.  Or maybe I should look at `express-jwt`?

And suddenly, I wonder... couldn't I just pass the token from my android app to the server at `auth/google/callback`?  That would make things a little simpler.  I think this must be a pipe dream, because I haven't found any information about doing it.  But if it's possible, how should I format the token/profile data in the request so the `passport.authenticate()` method recognizes it?  (JSON, form data, headers)

If this can't be done, I'm taking suggestions for well-documented token verification libraries for node...

Comment: I'm still having some trouble with this, are you using both `passport-google-oauth` and `passport-google-plus-token` in conjunction with each other operating on different routes. If I use just `passport-google-plus-token` how can I get to work within a browser (not Android or iOS app).

Comment: I never used `passport-google-plus-token`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still don't know about reusing the `google-passport-oauth2` route, but I did figure out how to validate Google's idToken using passport-google-id-token.

[The documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-id-token#authenticate-requests) says:

> The post request to this route should include a JSON object with the
>   key id_token set to the one the client received from Google (e.g.
>   after successful Google+ sign-in).

But it only works if it's sent as a query string (GET or POST works).

`https://localhost:8888/auth/googletoken?id_token=xxxxxxxxxx`

I have [a feeling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323286/3006854) this is not the most secure method, but I'll have to deal with that later.

EDIT: It turns out, the token is useless without the client ID (in your app), so it's OK to send it by querystring.

EDIT 2: One of the `google-id-token` devs [has reminded me](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token/issues/8#issuecomment-208572839) that the JSON will only be received if `body-parser` has been installed.

Comment: I am in a similar position you were. How did things work out?

Comment: I'm afraid this is still the method I'm using.  If you figure anything out, let me know.

Comment: I cant even get that to work. For some reason I just get invalid_token when I go post or get with the token in the query string....

Comment: Apparently i had access_token in my url instead of id_token. Google says to put it in the query string here so I don't think we should be concerned. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token

Comment: Yes, it seems like [the token is worthless without the client ID](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token/issues/8#issuecomment-201347857).  Which is good: now I don't have to fix anything.

Comment: But if you do want to use POST data, note that [`body-parser` is prerequesite](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token/issues/8#issuecomment-208572839).

Comment: how did this workout ? trying to do the same