# Remove personal information from mixpanel javascript tracking call

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, mixpanel, pii

I'm currently integrating with MixPanel's javascript library and have run into an issue that MixPanel does not seem to have thought about.  Our company deals with personally identifiable information(PII), and therefore some data that we pass as params are not appropriate for storage on a third-party service.  But MixPanel's default behavior is to include the full url for the current page and the referrer with every tracking event.  This makes sense to a degree, but we need to scrub some query parameters out of these fields.

It seems like MixPanel's documentation does not discuss an API for accomplishing this, so any advice from someone more experienced with MixPanel integration would be helpful.

Comment: did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

> "Our company deals with personally identifiable information(PII), and
>   therefore some data that we pass as params are not appropriate for
>   storage on a third-party service."

You should not be passing sensitive data as URL parameters.  This is a security no-no: the values end up in browser history (and thus can be retrieved by somebody looking through the browser history) and in server-side logs.  Always pass sensitive data through the HTTP body or headers instead.

References:

- https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/
- [Is an HTTPS query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)
- https://blog.gaborszathmari.me/2015/05/05/session-ids-as-query-parameters-must-die/
- http://owasp-aasvs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirement-9.3.html

Comment: This isn't sensitive data outside of the scope of a logged in user.  But following best practices, they are still things like internal ids we don't feel comfortable having on a third party's servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually override the Current URL by setting $current_url in your event, e.g.

```
mixpanel.track('My Event', {
  '$current_url': 'http://www.example.com'
});
```