# Does a Firewall "see" the Query string of a URL

Tags: http, url, parameters, block, firewall

I currently have the problem that I don't know **whether a firewall has access to the query string of a URL**, for example:

> www.example.com/muster.html?Name=Max+Mustermann&Ort=Musterstadt&PLZ=1234

If it checks the URL, does it only see `www.examle.com` or the rest of the URL as well?

The reason behind my question is that I *don't want the metadata that I send in the URL as a query string to be blocked by the firewall*.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the layer your firewall operates.

Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)#Network_layer_or_packet_filters:

> Network layer firewalls, also called packet filters, operate at a relatively low level of the TCP/IP protocol stack.

They basically check IP address and port.

Many modern products also work at application layer and with technologies like content filters - they can see the entire request - including the request parameters (but they would also see your post body).

By using HTTPS your query parameters are encrypted (check [Is an HTTPS query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)). In this case the firewall can't access these parameters. In practice there are e.g. corporate proxy scenarios where even HTTPS requests are intercepted, checked and re-signed by a trusted certificate. In these scenarios content filters can even see encrypted query parameters/ request information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What Jonas mentioned at the end is called `SSL inspection`. Web gateways like McAfee provide such a functionality to scan encrypted traffic. See http://www.webtorials.com/main/resource/papers/McAfee/paper2/inspecting-encrypted-web-traffic.pdf

Answer (score -1):

A Firewall is here to protect computer, he can check url and of course the data passed through URL.

Comment: Even if the POST Request is encrypted?