# Salesforce REST API how to avoid leaking sensitive data in query parameter

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to do query using REST API, and ran into the following problem:

Using GET request on the query endpoint exposes the entire query string, which may contain sensitive data such as SSN, phone number, etc...

`https://[instance-url].my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SSN__c = '123456789'`

How can I do such a query using rest api securely?
IS there an equivalent request I can make using at least POST request with post body being the query? since that part is encrypted over https.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, salesforce only provides a GET method for executing SOQL queries. One can write their own REST endpoint in their org that accepts a query in body and execute it, but thats a waste of time in my opinion.

Query string parameters are secured over `https`.  Its a common misconception, where people think whole url is open in plain text in transmission. When a request is made to an `https` url, first it establishes a Secure Tunnel to `[instance-url].my.salesforce.com` then transmits the rest of the url and any other data over the secure tunnel.

If you're worried about some man in the middle attack sniffing out the SSN from your query string, don't. One downside is, if you are accessing this url from a browser instead of a programmatic call, then there is a chance for browser to stored/cache for history or auto complete, then it won't be so good.

But I doubt if you would be able to do this via browser, as salesforce requires a bearer token set in Authorization header and there is no easy way that I know of to set headers while typing the url in the browser or clicking a link.

To know more about how query string is secure over https please refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I had the misconception that query params were not encrypted. However the security problem comes from different aspects such as this data ending up in logs, or any other server side issues according to the stackoverflow question you provided.

Comment: It's a common misconception that HTTPS adequately protects query string data. See https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/598.html and https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url

Comment: Let's not mix up HTTPS the protocol, and the Browser/User Agent which is the application that implements the protocol. The protocol is secure, but what the browser app does before applying or following the protocol standards cannot be labeled as inadequacy of the protocol. My answer does mention that browser can store/cache the URL, which implies exposure to unintended audience. So, not sure why I got down voted.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. [Parameterized Search API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_parameterized.htm). This option is available out of the box with POST as the method. The API is a RESTful interface to Salesforce's text-based search engine. Normally, text-based search uses SOSL as the query language. Parameterized Search API skips SOSL and gives you an easier option to work with.

If you POST the following body to `/services/data/v48.0/parameterizedSearch`

```js
{
   "q": "123456789",
   "sobjects": [
      {
         "name": "Contact",
         "where": "SSN__c = '123456789'"
      }
   ],
   "fields": ["id"]
}
```

you should see something like this as the response, assuming single record is returned by search (ID is redacted):

```js
{
  "searchRecords" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/003..."
    },
    "Id" : "003..."
  } ]
}
```

The value of `q` key in the JSON payload must be the same as the value in the `where` key/clause. You're doing a full-text search on `123456789` across all objects and all fields in the search index. This could return many records..but you're filtering the search down in a structured way to guarantee that you'll only see `Contact` records where `SSN__c = '123456789'`. As long as the objects + fields you're trying to retrieve are present in the index the results you'll see via Parameterized Search in this specific example are going to be the same as that of a SOQL query via `/query`

2. Custom REST API (aka [Apex REST](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices) / Apex web service). This is a typical implementation option for cases like yours. You can send whatever payload via POST and then process it however you like.

Apex class:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/findcontactbyssn')
global class ContactResource {
    @HttpPost
    global static void findContactBySSN() {
        SearchRequest input = (SearchRequest)JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(),SearchRequest.class);
        Contact c = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SSN__c = :input.ssn];
        SearchResponse output = new SearchResponse();
        output.id = c.id;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(output));
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;  
    }

    class SearchRequest {
      public String ssn {get;set;}
    }

    class SearchResponse {
      public String id {get;set;}
    }
}
```

POST to `/services/apexrest/findcontactbyssn` with

```js
{
 "ssn": "12345678"
}
```

and you should see this response:

```js
{
 "id": "003..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Parametrized Search looks very interesting. It does seem slower, and maybe its perhaps it searches everything?