# How OAuthV2 applications protect from replay attacks on the callback from the authorization server?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'll take the example from [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type). Let's say the `Resource Owner` wants to authorize the `Application` example-app.com to have access to some of his resources.

1) The `Resource Owner` will be directed to a URI in the `Authorization Server`, for example:

```
https://authorization-server.com/auth
 ?response_type=code
 &client_id=29352915982374239857
 &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample-app.com%2Fcallback
 &scope=create+delete
 &state=xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch
```

2) The `Resource Owner` will authenticate with the `Authorization Server` and will be redirected to:

```
https://example-app.com/redirect
 ?code=g0ZGZmNjVmOWIjNTk2NTk4ZTYyZGI3
 &state=xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch
```

**Question:** What if someone else copies the URI from Step 2) and makes a  request to that same  URI? Assume that the request from the `Attacker` will be processed before the `Resource Owner`'s. For example, an `Attacker` sending the same request to:

```
https://example-app.com/redirect
 ?code=g0ZGZmNjVmOWIjNTk2NTk4ZTYyZGI3
 &state=xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch
```

It looks to me that the `Application` can now access the resources from the `Resource Owner` and share it with the `Attacker`, specially if the `Application` creates a session with the requester once the `code` is validated. Does that make any sense? How to protect against that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take advantage of that, the attacker first needs to obtain the redirect url. This is the hard part. The redirect will get sent from the authorization server to the resource owner, and requires HTTPS.

Once an attack is able to snoop on this, most security is out of the window.

Comment: So the redirect url is as safe as [passing sensitive information on query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure) over HTTPs?

Comment: @M.M yes, passing tokens via urls does indeed have issues, especially given that these urls may end up in logs and caches. However, the `code` should be very short-lived and single-use, which should mitigate this quite a bit.

Comment: If the attacker somehow gets access to the code _before_ the code was validated, there will be a problem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for answering the question and the details on the URL!

Comment: @M.M you might also be interested to know that OAuth2.1 is under development, has a good draft and will require additional signatures on authorization_code. However, I think this issue is still unchanged.