# How do I properly pass an group ID parameter into the GroupMe API

Tags: python, curl, get, http-method, groupme

I am trying to return a specific group by ID in GroupMe using Python. The official documentation states that, to get a specific group, you append the base URL with `/groups/:id` and add the group ID number as a parameter (along with the access token). From the documentation, it says that the ID needs to be a string.

So, I am aware of the fact that the server is not receiving the correct form, but I don't know how to send the 'correct form,' whatever that may be.

As a note, I am running Python 3.10.

This is the code that I am using:

```
import requests
import json

parameter = {'id':'12345678'}

url_link = 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/:id?token=token123455'

answer = requests.get(url_link, params=parameter)
print(answer.json())
```

However, every time I pass the parameter (both as a JSON or a query string), the API always returns with:

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errors":["param is not a number"]}}
```

To further test it, I tried to use cURL:

```
url -X GET https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/:id?token=token12345&id=12345678
```

Got the same error as above. I'm pretty stumped on what to do; any help?

This is my first post here (and my background isn't in computer science or software engineering) so I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: i ran the same code and get a different error message. `{'meta': {'code': 401, 'errors': ['unauthorized']}}`

Comment: The HTTP status code 401 indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Comment: That returns because you have to send your access token in the request (it is the token parameter in the query string in my question above.) You get your access token from the GroupMe Developers homepage once you log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax `:id` means a path parameter. You *replace* it with the actual value of group `id`.

Also [authentication documentation](https://dev.groupme.com/tutorials/oauth) mentions two ways of passing the access token. The one employing headers should be the preferred one. Passing sensitive data in URLs is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323286/21350362).

Concerning these, retrieval of group information could be done so:

```py
import requests
import json

url = f'https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/{group_id_value}'

headers = {
    'X-Access-Token': your_token_value,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: @BarelyDeveloper you may mark this answer as accepted then.