# How does Dropbox's landing page download process work so well?

Tags: javascript, redirect, download, installation

On Dropbox's home page (http://www.dropbox.com), when a user clicks the download button, it launches 1) the proper installer for the user's browser *and* 2) redirects them to the appropriate install instructions page *without* being flagged by major browsers as a pop-up.

I've tried to implement their method with Javascript using this code:

```
<a href="http://downloadlink.exe"     onClick="window.open('http://InstallInstructionsURL.com');">
```

But various browsers block this and flag it as a pop-up. And it only captures one part of the problem (and not the part of redirecting the user to the appropriate browser and install instructions page).

Dropbox's home page works great. But I'm having a tough time figuring out what they do, and how to do it myself.

As a software developer who is still developing download apps for the desktop/browser, I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start automatic download of a file in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

In fact the magic is not in the button, it is just normal [link](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?src=index), but the page with that link really has small trick to start downloading:

```
<div id="page-content">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
     if (!Prototype.Browser.IE) {
        window.location = '\x2fdownload\x3fplat\x3dwin';
     }
    });
</script>
```

Here the load event listener is registered as function that changes `window.location`.
It is common approach for javascript redirect ([more details](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location)), but as far as response content is `application/octet-stream` nothing happened with current page and standard save window is shown.