# Response.Redirect is not working

Tags: asp.net

i am writing a code where after clicking one button one page will be redirected to another nd after opening 2nd page one pdf file will be download just like this website http://www.findwhitepapers.com/content22881 .But instead of opening the 2nd page and downloading the pdf file only pdf file is downloaded but 2nd page is not opening.1st page code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("2nd.aspx");
}
```

2nd page's code  is written below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = "guar-gum/Guar-gum-export-report.pdf";

    // The file name used to save the file to the client's system..

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    System.IO.Stream stream = null;
    try
    {
        // Open the file into a stream. 
        stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Guar-gum-export-report.pdf"), System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
        // Total bytes to read: 
        long bytesToRead = stream.Length;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        // Read the bytes from the stream in small portions. 
        while (bytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // Make sure the client is still connected. 
            if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // Read the data into the buffer and write into the 
                // output stream. 
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
                int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                Response.Flush();
                // We have already read some bytes.. need to read 
                // only the remaining. 
                bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get out of the loop, if user is not connected anymore.. 
                bytesToRead = -1;
            }
        }
        Response.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        // An error occurred.. 
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Close();




            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already coded to send the pdf in page2's response stream that is the reason for this behavior..

Comment: but how to ovrcm ds problem

Comment: ok. please help me out frm ds problm

Comment: your 1st option is not working. can you plase help me how to implement download option through handler

Comment: @SoumitaP I read again the question. The problem is similar to what I have replay you, you can not have both, download and show the page.

Comment: ok.but how it is working here? http://www.findwhitepapers.com/content22881

Comment: Check my answer that will open the page2 and download will also happen.

Comment: Response.Redirect() won't work after Response.Flush()

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to see on the 2nd page? All you have there is a pdf file. Do you expect an empty page?

Your redirect works fine. When you click the button a PDF file will be sent back to the browser and it will see it as a file that should be downloaded. No page will be sent to the browser so there is no page to see.

Comment: please check out http://www.findwhitepapers.com/content22881 page and click download now button.. i want dt same thing in my page also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Don't code what you have done in page2.aspx for file downloading instead put an `iframe` in the page2.aspx and set the `src` to the file Url.

I guess it is `guar-gum/Guar-gum-export-report.pdf` in your case. May be you should change this to start from root of the site by prefix `/` to the file url.

Put this in page2.aspx

```html
<iframe width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" src="[File location]"></iframe>
```

It is very simple way and No redirects or JavaScript and your Page2.aspx will also open.

### UPDATE

Based on the comments below this answer

I think there is no better solution but here is another mindbending one (psst! hope you and other like..) move the page2.aspx code **one for file download ONLY** to the third page page3.aspx and set `iframe.src` to page3.aspx

*Reference*

1. [SO - How to start automatic download of a file in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156715/468718)

Comment: What is happening ? Error message or behavior change or else ?

Comment: 2nd page is opening but pdf is not downloading.

Comment: Ok I think there is no better solution but here is another mindbending one (psst hope you and other like).. move the page2.aspx code **one for file download ONLY** to the third page page3.aspx and set `iframe.src` to page3.aspx

Comment: this iframe concept is not working... is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: ok [here](http://www.harshbaid.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/WebApplication1.gif) is the working example demo site I have created. open in chrome or so and if dwld not happen then press ctrl+s to save the file and rename it to .zip from .gif to see the source.

Comment: Works now ? checked the [attachment](http://www.harshbaid.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/WebApplication1.gif) ?

Comment: autometic download is not happening here also.. is there any problem with my browser..

Comment: you mean 1. my [attachment](http://www.harshbaid.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/WebApplication1.gif) is not downloading or 2. Your code is not working ? if problem in 1. Then try right-click and 'save link as' or 'Save Target' if problem in 2. then what is current state of problem ?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error message or which part is not working instead of me asking you each time when it is not working..

Comment: Check the `Default.aspx` (which should be page2.aspx in your case) in the `html` and `Contact.aspx` (which should be page3.aspx as I said to send the download file) in the `aspx.cs` code.