# How to trigger a download from DataURL in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, data-url

I'm retrieving a file as a base64 string from the server and needs to implement download functionality in JavaScript. How can I achieve this.

I used download attribute on anchor tag but this doesn't support in IE.

window.open also doesn't support in IE because what I have is a data url

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start automatic download of a file in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: The answers talking about raw file. What I have is a base64 string

Comment: So you want to simulate a download as if this string had come from a file on the server?

Comment: Yes. The content comes from server to client as a base64 string when the download link is clicked by the user

Comment: Why can't you just download that file instead of retrieving it into a string?

Comment: I'm retrieving it through a MVC controller via an AJAX request

Comment: I don't think there's a way to fake a download.

Comment: Can't your AJAX-request return an url to where the user can retrieve the file then? That way you could just redirect them to that url or open it in a new window to start the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post it to the server and set the appropriate headers. There is afaik no other solution that will work in more browsers

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"png.png\");
```