# How to create 'save as' url?

Tags: xml, url, download, save-as

Is it possible to take a direct download url/link, and format it so when it is entered it automatically chooses to save as? This is not going to be done as a link in the HTML, this needs to be a url/link I could email someone that when clicked, or copy/pasted into a browser would run as a save as option.

Example:
**saveas_**http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlc/files/latest/download?source=carousel

I am trying to provide a link to a hosted xml file.

If you click the link, it tries to open the xml in your browser, but if you save as, it will actually download the file.

So if a save as switch on a URL is not possible, any recommendations to achieve the same result is appreciated.

This will be offered on machines I don't have control over, so choosing to modify the machines default action for opening xml files is not going to be a feasible option.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2897650/2366976) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer) covers the same topic and might have the solution you're looking for.

Comment: For my needs, the save as command needs to be directly on the link, not in html, as I will be providing the link via email, IM etc.

Comment: porneL's dead simple solution would work best I think assuming you could zip the file first. I know my corporate email policy makes sending links to and downloading XML files hard and I have to always zip them to get around this. JavaScript obviously wouldn't be feasible for including in emails and such, but if you have access to a web server I like Tyler's idea.