# How do I set response headers in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=["POST"])
def hello():
    resp = make_response(render_template('hello.html'))
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

However, when I make a request from the browser to my server I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/hello. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have also tried this approach, setting the response headers "after" the request:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

No dice. I get the same error. Is there a way to just set the response headers in the route function? Something like this would be ideal:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=["POST"])
    def hello(response): # is this a thing??
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        return response
```

but I cant find anyway to do this. Please help.

**EDIT**

if I curl the url with a POST request like so:

```
curl -iX POST http://localhost:5000/hello
```

I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 291
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.6
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 03:58:42 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i would suggest using a middleware to solve this issue or just using the flask-cors extension

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    resp = flask.Response("Foo bar baz")
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

Look at [flask.Response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response) and [flask.make_response()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response)

But something tells me you have another problem, because the `after_request` should have handled it correctly too.

**EDIT**
I just noticed you are already using `make_response` which is one of the ways to do it.  Like I said before, `after_request` should have worked as well.  Try hitting the endpoint via curl and see what the headers are:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/your/endpoint
```

You should see

```
> curl -i 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.5
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 03:47:13 GMT
```

Noting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

**EDIT 2**
As I suspected, you are getting a 500 so you are not setting the header like you thought.  Try adding `app.debug = True` before you start the app and try again.  You should get some output showing you the root cause of the problem.

For example:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    resp = flask.Response("Foo bar baz")
    user.weapon = boomerang
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

Gives a nicely formatted html error page, with this at the bottom (helpful for curl command)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/private/tmp/min.py", line 8, in home
    user.weapon = boomerang
NameError: global name 'boomerang' is not defined
```

Comment: I have made Server = '' from response headers but still can see two keys, Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.5 and Server: 
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 42):

Use `make_response` of Flask something like

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    resp = make_response("hello") #here you could use make_response(render_template(...)) too
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

From [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.make_response),

> **flask.make_response(*args)**
>
> Sometimes it is necessary to set additional headers in a view. Because views do not have to return response objects but can return a value that is converted into a response object by Flask itself, it becomes tricky to add headers to it. This function can be called instead of using a return and you will get a response object which you can use to attach headers.

Comment: You can send the requests in the args: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.make_response

Answer (score 22):

This was how  added my headers in my flask application and it worked perfectly

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
    return response
```

Answer (score 20):

[According to the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#about-responses), you can return headers from your view function together with the response.

> If a tuple is returned the items in the tuple can provide extra
> information. Such tuples have to be in the form `(response, status)`,
> `(response, headers)`, or `(response, status, headers)`. The status value
> will override the status code and headers can be a list or dictionary
> of additional header values.

For example:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=["POST"])
def hello():
   return flask.make_response(), {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

Or:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=["POST"])
def hello():
   return {"foo": "bar"}, 200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

Answer (score 12):

This work for me

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return Response(headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set the response headers in Python Flask application using Flask application context using `flask.g`

This way of setting response headers in Flask application context using `flask.g` is thread safe and can be used to set custom & dynamic attributes from any file of application, this is especially helpful if we are setting custom/dynamic response headers from any helper class, that can also be accessed from any other file ( say like middleware, etc), this `flask.g` is global & valid for that request thread only.

Say if i want to read the response header from another api/http call that is being called from this app, and then extract any & set it as response headers for this app.

Sample Code: file: `helper.py`

```
import flask
from flask import request, g
from multidict import CIMultiDict
from asyncio import TimeoutError as HttpTimeout
from aiohttp import ClientSession

    def _extract_response_header(response)
      """
      extracts response headers from response object 
      and stores that required response header in flask.g app context
      """
      headers = CIMultiDict(response.headers)
      if 'my_response_header' not in g:
        g.my_response_header= {}
        g.my_response_header['x-custom-header'] = headers['x-custom-header']


    async def call_post_api(post_body):
      """
      sample method to make post api call using aiohttp clientsession
      """
      try:
        async with ClientSession() as session:
          async with session.post(uri, headers=_headers, json=post_body) as response:
            responseResult = await response.read()
            _extract_headers(response, responseResult)
            response_text = await response.text()
      except (HttpTimeout, ConnectionError) as ex:
        raise HttpTimeout(exception_message)
```

file: `middleware.py`

```
import flask
from flask import request, g

class SimpleMiddleWare(object):
    """
    Simple WSGI middleware
    """

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self._header_name = "any_request_header"

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        """
        middleware to capture request header from incoming http request
        """
        request_id_header = environ.get(self._header_name)
        environ[self._header_name] = request_id_header

        def new_start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info=None):
            """
            set custom response headers
            """
            # set the request header as response header
            response_headers.append((self._header_name, request_id_header))
            # this is trying to access flask.g values set in helper class & set that as response header
            values = g.get(my_response_header, {})
            if values.get('x-custom-header'):
                response_headers.append(('x-custom-header', values.get('x-custom-header')))
            return start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info)

        return self.app(environ, new_start_response)
```

Calling the middleware from main class

file : `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import asyncio
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from middleware import SimpleMiddleWare

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = SimpleMiddleWare(app.wsgi_app)
```