# Python, Flask: How to set response header for all responses

Tags: python, flask, http-headers

I want to set all of my http headers responses to something like this:

```
response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860304/how-do-i-set-response-headers-in-flask), but it only changes the header for one specific controller. I want to change all of my headers maybe in "before_request" function similar to the following logic. How can I do that?

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Comment: Just a note that the `X-Frame-Options` has been obsoleted by the `frame-ancestors` directive. More info on frame-ancestors https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors and an open-source lib to imlpement Flask CSP: https://github.com/twaldear/flask-csp

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Set the header in a [`@app.after_request()` hook](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request), at which point you have a response object to set the header on:

```
@app.after_request
def apply_caching(response):
    response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "SAMEORIGIN"
    return response
```

The [`flask.request` context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.request) is still available when this hook runs, so you can still vary the response based on the request at this time.

Comment: just to add to this. you should use the `@app.before_request` to get your header token and check for its validity.. (header should be sent with the request in javascirpt) and then your after request is where you should change the response headers

Comment: @JohnRuddell On stock, Flask does not enforce or provide token verification. Asserting that you should do this is not true at all.

Comment: @kevr if you have a token that provides validation to locked down api's (JWT for example with "Bearer" token header) then the before_request is a way to check the validity of your token. Thats all I was trying to say.

Comment: @opyate: that's a rather large edit you made there. Can you please use a comment to point out additional issues in future? I'm fairly active on SO and always open to suggestions.

Comment: @opyate: I rolled back that edit. Hacking up the `after_requests_func` mapping is a much more advanced topic and perhaps should be subject of a separate question and answer pair.

Comment: @opyate: last but not least, the `after_request` decorator does **the exact same thing** your edit did without a decorator: append to the `self.after_request_funcs[None]` list. You don't appear to have a corner case there at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough. CORS broke for me unless I did it the func-y way.

Comment: It oughtn't, though, so I'm stumped: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2433522d2967b8a5e46f16de587a8fac5088a47c/flask/app.py#L1431

Comment: I love the simplicity of Martijn Pieters' answer, but if caused conflicting X-Frame-Options headers, with one that I suspect gunicorn or something else below Flask in the stack was setting to DENY. The browser in the case of such a conflict falls back to DENY, so I was left about where I started. Further research led to this small tweak to his answer that is now working for me:

`response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "frame-ancestors 'self'"`

Answer (score 8):

The `@app.after_request() hook` was not adequate for my use case.

My use case is as follows: I have a google cloud function, and I want to set the CORS headers for all responses. There are possibly multiple responses, as I have to validate the input and return if there are issues with it, I have to process data and possibly return early if something fails etc. So I've created a helper function as follows:

```py
# Helper function to return a response with status code and CORS headers
def prepare_response(res_object, status_code):
    response = flask.jsonify(res_object)
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
    return response, status_code
```

Thus, when I want to return a response (always with CORS headers), I can now call this function and I do not duplicate the response.headers setup necessary to enable CORS.

Answer (score 0):

We can set the response headers for all responses in Python Flask application gracefully using WSGI Middleware

This way of setting response headers in Flask application context using middleware is thread safe and can be used to set custom & dynamic attributes, read the request headers this is especially helpful if we are setting custom/dynamic response headers from any helper class.

file: `middleware.py`

```
import flask
from flask import request, g

class SimpleMiddleWare(object):
    """
    Simple WSGI middleware
    """

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self._header_name = "any_request_header"

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        """
        middleware to capture request header from incoming http request
        """
        request_id_header = environ.get(self._header_name)  # reading all request headers
        environ[self._header_name] = request_id_header  

        def new_start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info=None):
            """
            set custom response headers
            """
            # set the above captured request header as response header
            response_headers.append((self._header_name, request_id_header))
            # example to access flask.g values set in any class thats part of the Flask app & then set that as response header
            values = g.get(my_response_header, {})
            if values.get('x-custom-header'):
                response_headers.append(('x-custom-header', values.get('x-custom-header')))
            return start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info)

        return self.app(environ, new_start_response)
```

Calling the middleware from main class

file : `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import asyncio
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from middleware import SimpleMiddleWare

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.wsgi_app = SimpleMiddleWare(app.wsgi_app)
```

Comment: What is `g`? in the import statement & `values = g.get(my_response_header, {})`. Also what is `my_response_header`?