Flask: How to return the "Retry-After" header (flask.Response.retry_after ?)
I have a Python + Flask web app that serves files.
The file needs a time to be made, that may vary from few seconds to few minutes.
If a request comes and the file is not ready, the "Error 503" is sent to the user, as here:
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, Response
import datetime


@app.route('/x/<string:file_name>')
def make_file(file_name):
    if creation_of_file(file_name) == 'success':
        return send_from_directory('files', file_name)
    else:
        return 'File not ready. Try again later', 503

I would like to improve it, by adding the "Retry-After" header, together with the seconds the user has to wait before the placing of a new request. Something like this:
return 'File not ready. Try again later', 503, Retry-After=300

I already tried this without success:
return 'File not ready. Try again later', 503, Response.retry_after(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300))

I searched extensively, including at stackoverflow, but could not find any relevant documentation on the sintaxe to include the Retry-After, but just a short mention of flask.Response.retry_after, that comes with no examples or any relevant information on how to use it.
How can I include the "Retry-After=300" header (300 seconds) together with the 503 error and the "File not ready. Try again later" message?

You'll want to return a Response object rather than multiple values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860304/how-do-i-set-response-headers-in-flask#25860353

@OneCricketeer Thank you for the hint. Following your link I could implement as desired.
