# create image download button support all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I try to make a image download button that works correctly in all browsers(ie8+) and i try this codes:

```
<!-- don't work with IE and Safari -->
<div>
    <a href="/image.jpg" download>Download</a>
</div>
```

and

```
<!-- this code don't work at all -->
<div>
    <iframe width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" src="/image.jpg"></iframe> 
    Download
</div>
```

[according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2):

The `download` attribute is part of HTML5, and won't work in legacy browsers. If you want to force an image download you would need to do something server-side to serve the image in binary format with the correct MIME type.

Answer (score -1):

The download attribute are not supported in IE8. You can see which browsers that supports it here.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download