# How to download a file when load?

Tags: javascript

I used below code for the create and download the file. But below the code only work when click the link. so how to download the file by default load. without click.

```
     <script>

array=[{a:'1',b:'2'},{x:'3',y:'4'}];

function dl(array,filename){
var b=document.createElement('a');
b.download=filename;
b.textContent=filename;
b.href='data:application/json;base64,'+window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array))))
return b
}

document.body.appendChild(dl(array,'my.json'));


        </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer

Comment: kindly update the code here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
// see FileSaver.js
saveAs(content, "example.zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly the solution would be to 
replace `b.href` with `window.location`
your content will automatically load in the current tab.

Comment: document.body.appendChild(dl()); this code is needed? kindly delete unwanted code form my question please

Comment: please help. the file not download when use window.herf

Comment: @Maninblack it is not window.href it is window.location