# How to display a page and start the file download from it in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a method in my views.py that I've constructed with a http response

```
 # # content-type of response
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')

    # #decide file name
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ThePythonDjango.xls"'
#adding new sheets and data
                new_wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
new_wb.save(response)
```

This works fine if I only have response in my return 
But I also want to return a render

```
return  render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {"excel_data": seller_info, "message":message, "errormessage":errormessage})
```

I was wondering if there's a way to do that

Comment: It is impossible to make two responses from one :). Generaly it should first "return the render", and the rendered page should start the download via another HTTP request to a (separate) view. Maybe you could reword the question like "Hot to display a page and start the file download from it in django?".

Comment: i took your suggestion haha

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by making the view behave differently on the existence of some query parameter, the `download` parameter, for example. Actually, it would be equivalent to having two separate views:

1. The first view should return the rendered HTML response, which automatically starts the file download. For example via an iframe, just put this code into the template:

   ```
   <iframe width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" src="?download"></iframe>
   ```

   You can see some other methods to start automatic download here: [How to start automatic download of a file in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer)
2. The second view should contain your XLS generation code and return the HttpResponse with the XLS contents.

Combining this into a single view could look like:

```
def xls_download_view(request):
    if 'download' in request.GET:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ThePythonDjango.xls"'
        new_wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
        ...
        new_wb.save(response)
        return response
    else:
        ...
        return render(...)
```

Comment: So I have a question about this. My form with the download button takes an upload file and renders a validation report, listing issues with the content of the file, which the user must fix and re-upload.  But, some issues can be fixed automatically. Others can't. So I wanted to have the results page automatically download a file with some fixes and present the remaining fixes in a report under the form (as is done already). I was hoping to stream the file to avoid hitting the disk again, but it sounds to me like if I do what you suggest, I would have to save the file to disk and then grab it?