# asp.net make button show different view of MultiView AND download a file

Tags: asp.net

I have a page on my site on which users have to fill out details before they can download a document.  The user details section is on the first view in a MultiView control.

After filling out their details I'd like the user to click a button which will show them a file download prompt (I've done this successfully with an ashx handler) *then* redirect them to the second view page of the MultiView which will say "thank you for downloading" or something like that.

I've tried the usual `Response.Redirect("~/DownloadHandler.ashx");` within the button click event handler, but obviously this prevents the page completing the postback and showing the last page of the MultiView.

Is there a way around this, or should I just change my UI to accommodate this?

**EDIT:**
I've concluded that it's better to just provide a hyperlink to the document (on my confirmation page, and change the wording accordingly) as this provides a consistent user experience independent of the browser they're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and take them to the second view of the MultiView. Add a javascript method that will download the document, and trigger it from your codebehind.1 E.g.,

In your page:

```
<script>
function downloadFile(url) {
 window.location = url;
 //you could also try window.open(url, 'Download')
}
</script>
```

In your code behind:

```
script = string.Format("downloadFile('{0}');", "DownloadHandler.ashx");
Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "download", script, true);
```

You could also add a delay (using setTimeout) before the file is downloaded.

More info:
[[Initiating a file download that works well, even in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727934/initiating-a-file-download-that-works-well-even-in-ie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727934/initiating-a-file-download-that-works-well-even-in-ie)